# Akka Ask with Timed Retry

Tags: scala, akka

Here is a simple function that I wrote to do an Akka "ask" with a timed retry. There is an obvious race condition that I'm not sure how to solve.

```
def askWithRetry(actor: ActorRef, message: Any, timeout: Timeout): Future[Any] =
  (actor ? message)(timeout) recoverWith { case e: AskTimeoutException =>
      // do a retry. currently there is no retry limit for simplicity.
      askWithRetry(actor, message, timeout)
    }
```

Normally, this works. The "ask" or `?` creates a temporary intermediate actor for each call. If the target sends a response message, the temporary "ask actor" puts the result in the Future as a successful completion. If the target doesn't respond in time, the future completes with a timeout exception and the recoverWith process does a retry.

However, there is a race condition. If the target sends the response message to the temporary "ask actor", but a timeout is processed before the response message, then the response message will be lost. The retry process resends a new request using a new temporary actor. Since the response message was sent to the previous temporary "ask actor" which is now defunct it will not be processed and is lost.

How can I fix this?

I can write a custom version of the Ask pattern with the retry logic built-in that fixes this race condition... I hate to use unnecessary custom code if there is a more standard option though.

**UPDATE**: Here is the custom version I ended up going with:

```
object AskWithRetry {
  def askWithRetry(context: ActorContext, actor: ActorRef, message: Any, retryInterval: Duration, maxRetries: Option[Int]): Future[Any] = {
    val p = Promise[Any]

    val intermediate = context.actorOf(props(p, actor, message, retryInterval, maxRetries))

    p.future
  }

  def props(promise: Promise[Any], target: ActorRef, message: Any, retryInterval: Duration, maxRetries: Option[Int]): Props =
          Props(new AskWithRetryIntermediateActor(promise, target, message, retryInterval, maxRetries))
}

class AskWithRetryIntermediateActor(promise: Promise[Any], target: ActorRef, message: Any, retryInterval: Duration, var maxRetries: Option[Int]) extends Actor {
  def doSend(): Unit = target ! message

  def receive: Receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      maxRetries match {
        case None =>
          //println(s"Retrying. Infinite tries left. ${message}")
          doSend()
        case Some(retryCount) =>
          if (retryCount > 0) {
            //println(s"Retrying. ${retryCount-1} tries left. ${message}")
            maxRetries = Some(retryCount - 1)
            doSend()
          } else {
            //println(s"Exceeded timeout limit. Failing. ${message}")
            if (!promise.isCompleted) {
              promise.failure(new AskTimeoutException("retry limit reached"))
            }
            context.stop(self)
          }
      }
    case otherMessage: Any =>
      if (!promise.isCompleted) {
        //println(s"AskWithRetry: completing ${otherMessage}")
        promise.success(otherMessage)
      }
      context.stop(self)
  }

  context.setReceiveTimeout(retryInterval)
  doSend()
}
```

Comment: In all honesty, I would stay away from writing a new version of ask.  It's a common misconception that one has a unique problem that requires a unique solution.  In all reality, there is probably a more simple solution; writing a custom implementation of a pre-existing piece of framework code should be a last resort.  In your case, why not just bump up the ask timeout to better account for situations where the timeout happens just before a response is received?  If you're going to do a retry, then the caller is going to be waiting longer anyway.

Comment: I agree with the mindset of avoiding custom solutions wherever possible. However, the standard solution had a race condition problem and I couldn't find an appropriate standard solution, so I posted here, and no one has any better ideas. My custom solution is pretty light and simple. I edited it into the original question post.

Comment: I was waiting to hear back from you regarding my suggestion to simply bump up the timeout before posting a solution.  Given that you are eating up additional clock with your retry isn't it just easier and simpler to do that?

Comment: Also, raising the timeout wouldn't fix the race condition and isn't appropriate for the issue. I need to regularly send retries at a certain interval.

Comment: BTW, this is for the official Akka class by Roland Kuhn on cousera. Assignment 6 on the reactive class. The course is officially out of session but you can still do the assignments and get them graded.

Comment: What was the exact requirement from that assignment that got you going down this path?  I'd be curious to see what Roland thinks of your solution.

Comment: The assignment clearly states you need to retry at 100 ms intervals. For some paths, it is required, that you propagate failure at 1 second. I just posted the same issue on the coursera site and would also love to see Roland Kuhn or another official TypeSafe guy give feedback.

Comment: I think it makes sense, I did something like that and I also wrote a blog post and some tests for it: http://blog.astrac.me/coding/2014/02/19/akka-actor-retry/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your instincts are good. If you want custom actor-logic, you should write it.

The custom ask-waiting actor should send the message to `actor` and `scheduleOnce` a message to *itself* to retry. That way, both responses and timeouts arrive via the `receive` method and you don't have any races.

Comment: I'd argue this is a common use case and I wouldn't label it "custom actor logic".